# Python: creating a set of vector coordinates or a matrix from a multidimensional table

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, multidimensional-array

If I have a table with two coordinates, say `(A,B)`, and at each coordinate entry there there is an value C. Such as:

```
      B_1   B_2    B_3  ...
A_1   C1    C2     C3   ...
A_2   C4    etc    ...  ...
A_3   ...
...
```

What I need is to convert this into a matrix format, ideally an array of arrays of the form `[ [A_1, B_1], [A_1, B_2], ... ]` and one array of the corresponding C values `[ C1, C2, ]` for each `[A,B]` point.

The reason I need this is because I actually have a 3D (and potentially later a 4D) table that I need to do this to so that I can then do linear interpolation for the C values.

Are there any packages or ways to do this in numpy or maybe pandas?

At the moment I have this table on paper, it would be extremely tedious to go through all the permutations of points (A,B,C) and their associated values. Much easier to write it in as a table and then convert if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: have you looked at : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. That's what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quiet ambiguous. Do you want A and B to be indices that point to a certain C? Or do A and B carry values themselves?

With some guesstimation on my side, maybe this will help:

```
import numpy as np

# A values
A = np.arange(0, 8)
# B values
B = np.arange(16, 24)
# The corresponding C Values, where C[n, m] corresponds to A_n, B_m
C = np.arange(8**2).reshape(8, 8)

# Creating an 3x8x8 Array
ABC = np.meshgrid(A, B) + [C,]
ABC = np.array(ABC)

print ABC
```

you also might want to look into itertools.combinations

Comment: Thanks for the help. What I meant was to create two arrays: one all the possible set of coordinates (A_n, B_m) and one with the associated C[n, m] values.
Actually, I ended up turning my table into a pandas dataframe, and now I see how to do it, it should actually be quite simple with some for loops.

Comment: Actually I ran your code, yes that is what I was trying to do with the meshgrid function. Although I guess what my real problem was is that I had to basically 'manually' create the table in the first place by copying off some paper.

Comment: _my real problem was is that I had to basically 'manually' create the table_ Welp, unfortunately there is no module that help with this kind of problem ;) However it is quiet easy to load NumPy arrays from files (be it binary or plain text)